# How to check radio buttons and option list in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

In my application I have to use PyQt4, and I want to be able to check radio buttons and option list.

When I want to pass a parameter to the text field type i do this:

```
doc = QWebView.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
first_name = doc.findFirst("input[id=f_name]")
first_name.setAttribute("value", "John")
```

But how to set the value for radio button:

```
    <li id="signup-list-gender" class="gender" >
                    <span class="gender-label">     Gender:
<span class="formNote">(Optional)</span></span>
                    <label for="signup-gender-male"><input id="signup-gender-male" class="gender" tabindex="9" type="radio" name="gender" value="m" > Male</label>
                    <label for="signup-gender-female"><input id="signup-gender-female" class="gender" tabindex="10" type="radio" name="gender" value="f" > Female</label>
                </li>
                <li id="signup-list-birthdate" class="birthdate">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the attributed "checked" on the radio button, something like this (i did't test this code):

```
doc = QWebView.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
male = doc.findFirst("input[id=signup-gender-male]")
male.setAttribute("checked", "true")
```

For radio buttons attributes check [here](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm)